# (High school Java homework help) Confusion on converting English letters to morse code

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am doing a project for my high school computer science class and I am running into some confusion. I am instructed to write a program which translates a user-inputted message from English to Morse code. I have completed the bulk of the assignment, but I can't seem to figure out how exactly to go about actually converting the user's message to Morse code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class MorseCode
{
public MorseCode()
{

}

//Reads in file containing Morse code and stores into an array of Strings
public static String [] readFile() throws IOException
{
    String [] codes = new String[36];
    int index = 0;
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("morsecode.txt"));

    while( fileScanner.hasNextLine() )
    {
        codes[index] = fileScanner.nextLine();
        index++;
    }

    return codes;
}

//Converts the array of morse codes to an array of its corresponding letter
public static String [] findChars(String [] morseCode)
{
    String [] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
                          "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};

    for( int index = 0; index < morseCode.length; index++)
    {
        morseCode[index] = alphabet[index];
    }

    return morseCode;
}
}
```

### Main

As of right now just used to test to make sure everything works as intended. Both the Morse code and its alphabetical and numeric equivalent outputs correctly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class MorseCodeTester
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Original Morse Code
    String [] morseCode = MorseCode.readFile();

    //Conversion to standard english letters
    String [] toConvert = MorseCode.readFile();
    String [] codeToLetters = MorseCode.findChars(toConvert);

    for( int index = 0; index < morseCode.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(morseCode[index]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for( int index = 0; index < morseCode.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(codeToLetters[index]);
    }
}
}
```

As stated previously, my confusion is coming from the actual conversion of English to Morse code, after the user inputs the desired message. If anybody could point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Comment: do you Google it? [this link](http://www.onlineconversion.com/morse_code.htm)  will help

Answer (score 4):

You could store each character in a Map along with its corresponding morse code string. e.g.

```
HashMap<String, String> codes = new HashMap<String, String>();
codes.put("a", ".-");
codes.put("b", "-...");
```

Then when converting a string, you could use the map to find the corresponding morse code string for each character of the string to be converted.

For example:

```
String str = "To be converted to morse";
StringBuilder morseSB = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++)
{
    morseSB.append(codes.get(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)).toLowerCase()));
}

String morseResult = morseSB.toString();
```

Note: you will need to add some precautionary checks. e.g. checking if the result of codes.get() is null and you may need to handle other characters like spaces and periods.

Comment: Thats better :) haha. While this is probably the best way to do this problem I think that it might not actually help the OP out that much though.

Comment: Why not? AFAIK it is not possible to convert english to morse using an algorithm and some sort of map or look up table is required.

Comment: I was more hinting towards the OPs current knowledge of Java given how they attempted the question thus far.

Answer (score 0):

this function convert "Hello world" to Morse code

```
public static String charToMorse( String s ){
    if( s.equals( "H" ) || s.equals("h"))
        return "....";
    else if ( s.equals( "E" ) || s.equals("e"))
        return "."
    // other alphabet will placed here
}
```

and write another method to traverse string's character

```
public static void showMorse( String s ){
    for( int i=0 ; i < s.length() ; i++ )
        System.out.printf( "%s " , charToMorse( s[i] ) );
    System.out.println();
}
```

this image show Morse code you need
[image: Morse code]